# LaTeX for Music vs Finale26 Make Music

Tags: music, lattice

What are the differences between LaTeX for Music (consider the best list of packages) and Finale26 Make Music?

Furthermore on Overleaf, for example, is it possible listen to music?

Comment: what are these packages? You give no links. `Finale26 Make Music` doesn't appear to be tex related at all looking at google?

Comment: Yes, please be more specific.

Comment: I do not know any play option in MusiXTeX, and I think this is the biggest difference with a lot of music notation software. The advantage of using MusiXTeX is that you can write music directly in a (text) document, and that you can place everything everywhere, while there are no automatisms. Besides, you type code (with a lot of music based abbreviations), so you do not need a mouse or a special keyboard.

Comment: Please, don't close this question, Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me put your question in some context.

*For moderators*: I summarize the experience, observations, and features, not opinion.

**(A) Latex** made TeX more comfortable, with the objective to do typesetting for publications: "writing beautiful books", as the inventor put it.

**(B) Sheet note notation programs** are dedicated to writing down music easily, e.g. via mouse or MIDI-keyboard. To listen to sheet notes, they support MIDI, which makes notes audible via synthesizers. Doesn't matter if we talk about Finale, MuseScore, Dorico etc.

(A) Yes, you can put notes, staff etc. into Latex, if you want. But it is more tedious, than it has to be if you think in terms of quick results.

(B) And No, you probably won't be able to create any useful text documentation via some Sheet Notation program, besides a few lines of text. I'm almost certain, none of these will typeset Math ...

(A) Nevertheless some enthusiasts spent time making music printable via Latex. See e.g. here: https://ctan.org/topic/music?lang=en (you'll see some using Lilypond, a text-based free notation program), or here: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/musictex (MIDI to TeX).

(A) A typical use case of using Latex with music notation is e.g. publishing a songbook, or workbooks as a printing house. Another might be preparing lectures for students ... but it might not be mandatory to use Latex for that purpose. Sheet notation programs might do all you need.

(B) A typical use case for using Sheet note notation software would be being a composer. The printing house may join all your songs and songlets or musical fragments to something, which can be published and sold to a reasonable market.

So, if you want to put notes on paper, or listen to notes (which is more or less MIDI) ... go with free MuseScore and similar. Overleaf won't help you much, as far as I know.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but (A) and (B) mean, ... What?

Comment: @Puck If you read it carefully you might come to the conclusion, as I did, that (A) refers to LaTeX and (B) refers to other kinds of program. (further  comment about your style which I decided to delete) --- GOM

Comment: +1: I took the liberty to correct some typos.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my typos :)

Comment: I think that "Latex made TeX more comfortable" is also opinion-based. But it is a majority opinion.